# In Spring how to generate controllers for jpa entities?

Tags: eclipse, spring, jpa

Thats my question, i know how to generate entities from database using JPA, but the next step is generate the controllers for the entities like Neatbeans.

Is there a way using Spring in Eclipse to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "controllers"? Your business logic?

Comment: @MaDa In netbeans for example you can generate JPA Controllers for entities classes. It generates basic queries from database. Is there a way to make it in Eclipse like in Netbeans?